# MongoDB Aggregation Query Self Join

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have this data:

```
[
  { "_id": 1,  "B": 1, "C": 1 },
  { "_id": 2,  "B": 1, "C": 1 },
  { "_id": 3,  "B": 1, "C": 2 },
  { "_id": 5,  "B": 2, "C": 1 },
  { "_id": 6,  "B": 2, "C": 1 },
  { "_id": 7,  "B": 2, "C": 3 },
  { "_id": 8,  "B": 3, "C": 1 },
  { "_id": 9,  "B": 3, "C": 1 },
  { "_id": 10, "B": 3, "C": 1 }
]
```

What I want to know:

I like to get all distinct "B"s for which no "C"s exist with the value 2 or 3.

For the given data the result should be only 3 because for the other "B"s rows exist with "C" values 2 or 3.

In SQL I would create a left outer join to get this.

Answer (score 1):

The following query should do

```
db.getCollection('foo').distinct("B", {"C" : {$nin: [2, 3]}});
```

Comment: This is not what I want. Your query filters out the rows with C 2 and 3 and then gives me the unique Bs.

Answer (score 0):

I found out this query returns the correct result:

```
db.mytest.distinct("B", {"B" : {$nin: db.mytest.distinct("B", {"C" : {$in: [2, 3]}})}});
```